# show this is a orthogonal basis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

let $f_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{inx}$ show that the set $ T = \{ f_n \}$ is an orthogonal basis on $L^2([-\pi,\pi]) \subset H$.

I have shown it is orthogonal, but not a basis. My idea was to take an element g in $T^\perp$ and show that element must be $0$:

if $g \in T^\perp$ then $<g,f_n> = 0 \iff \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} < g , e^{inx}> 0 $ but I cant conclude $g = 0$

Comment: why is it negative rating?

Comment: You can use Stone-Weierstrass theorem on the algebra generated by the $f_n$-s ($n\in\Bbb Z$): its closure in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ must contain its closure in $C^0[-\pi,\pi]$. But the latter is the whole $C^0[-\pi,\pi]$, which is a dense subset of $L^2$.